# How to select rows from a table by selecting combination of related data in a particular column? MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like;

**tablea**

[image: tablea]

```
4c4fedf7    OMoy3Hoa
4c4fedf7    yiWDGB4D
broe4AMb    A9rLRawV
broe4AMb    mi9rLmZW
nhrtK9ce    yEsBoYLj
rEEtK9gt    A9rLRawV
rEEtK9gt    mi9rLmZW
rEEtK9Hh    A9rLRawV
rEEtK9Hh    msBWz8CQ
```

If I give the input like `A9rLRawV`,`mi9rLmZW`. I want an output like;

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
```

The output is generated as a result of `A9rLRawV`,`mi9rLmZW` combination. Here, `broe4AMb` and `rEEtK9gt` both have `A9rLRawV` and `mi9rLmZW` associated in tablea. I made a query, but I get output like;

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
rEEtK9Hh
```

My query is like;

```
SELECT DISTINCT prodid
FROM tablea
WHERE tagid IN ('A9rLRawV','mi9rLmZW');
```

The output is like this because I think, `reetK9Hh` has `A9rLRawV` associated with it in tablea. But i don't want that entry to appear because it doesn't have `mi9rLmZW` associated with it.

Here is the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12223/2/0

Does it require a SELF JOIN. What will be the most 'efficient' method? Is it possible to achieve this with MySQL alone or with support of PHP? How can I do this / fix this?

Comment: yeehaw text data this time :P  Oh and a fiddle too

Comment: @Drew yea.. I "really" want to solve this, thats why... ;)

Comment: just let us know whether or not one of the below works

Comment: @Drew ,xQbert 's solution works like charm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I firmly believe this can be resolved by SQL alone.  Get the data you need from the database.  Have PHP do the presentation.  Why? Typically the Database can parse data much faster than you can through code on a webserver/middleware server.

As to how... Read up on `having` clauses and `group by`:

What I've done here is group by prodID to ensure all prodIDs are returned.  mySQL extends the group by clause and while it may allow a having clause to exist without a group by, you will not get the desired results without grouping by prodid.  The having a gets a distinct count of both tags requested in the where.  Note: I added `distinct` to the count on tagID as I was unsure if your overall data could have duplicate tagIds for each prodid.  we could eliminate it if we know values are distinct.

The # can be dynamically set based on the number of TagIDs provided if needed.

```
SELECT prodid
FROM tablea
WHERE tagID in ('A9rLRawV','mi9rLmZW')
GROUP BY  prodid
HAVING count(distinct tagID)=2
```

[SQL FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12223/11/0)

I prefer this approach as it scales better than a self join as you indicated might be needed.  Pass in two parameters: one for the tags one for the number of tags.  (I do so hope you're using paramaterized queries with your PHP) With self joins you have to write dynamic SQL to handle each additional tag so if you have 3, 4,5 more joins.  This way you just pass in the 5 values and the number 5; and get a list back of all those that match.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Don't forget your index @blaster

Comment: @Drew its a composite primary key

Comment: don't forget to do a `show create table xyz` to help us out with that output. It saves everyone from guessing for an hour. We do afterall strive for performance, like what xQbert has done. So why leave it to chance

Answer (score 1):

Like you assumed, a self join helps. Use this query

```
SELECT a.prodid
FROM tablea AS a
INNER JOIN tablea AS b
           ON a.prodid = b.prodid
WHERE a.tagid = 'A9rLRawV' and b.tagid = 'mi9rLmZW'
```

This here you join the table with itself and the matching pairs have both `A9rLRawV` (in the main table `a`) and `mi9rLmZW` (in the joined table `b`).

Here's your updated SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12223/13

The results are as wished:

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
```